# Why won't my .ajax request work?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The code I want to work:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "_Source/ajap/ajap.nlSrch.php",
        data: { sndJson : jsonData },
        dataType: "json", 
        processData: false,
        success: function(html) {
      $("#srchFrm").append(html);}
    });
```

The code that works:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "_Source/ajap/ajap.nlSrch.php",
        data: { sndJson : jsonData },
        success: function(html) {
      $("#srchFrm").append(html);}
    });
```

Unfortunately when I send the first one my post data looks like this "Array ()" and when I use the later I get this "Array ( [sndJson] => [\"8\",\"3\",\"6\",\"7\"] )".

I know that there has to be a simple explanation but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Help please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sending your data in a query string...

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"_Source/ajap/ajap.nlSrch.php?json="+jsonData,
        dataType:"json", 
        success: function(data) {
              $("#srchFrm").append(data);}
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {alert("Error!");}
    });
```

Comment: jsonData will be a json dude...what your trying to send the server??..check your json format ??

Comment: I've validated my json with jsonlint and just double checked it and I still get : [\"8\",\"3\",\"6\",\"7\"] . I could try and explode this but that is a wonky work around.

Answer (score 1):

You can use shorthand $.post instead of using low level ajax class --- because you don't need to advanced handling. So, this one will be great enough.

```
$(document.ready(function(){    
  $("#submit_button").click(function(){     
    $.post('php_script.php', {
     // here's what you want to send  
     // important -- double quotes, 'cause It's evals as valid JSON
     "var1" : "val1"  
     "var2" : "val2"    
    }, function (respond){
       try {
           var respond = JSON.parse(respond);
        } catch(e){
           //error - respond wasn't JSON
        }
    });  
  });
});
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Here you can handle variable or array you got from JavaScript
 * and send back if need.
 */ 
 print_r($_POST); // var1 = val1, var2 = val2
```

?>

Back to your question,
**Why  my .ajax request doesn't work?**
This is because JavaScript throws fatal error and stops further code execution.

You can catch and determine the error occasion, simply by adding

`try {} catch(){}` block to the statement you think may occur any error

Answer (score 0):

When you specify dataType: json, jQuery will automatically evaluate the response and return a Javascript object, in this case an array. You're taking the result and adding it as html to #srchForm, so it does not make sense to convert it to a javascript object. Use dataType: html, or none at all.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I see but then I take out that line of code and I still get "Array ()". This is very frustrating. i wish I could just pass an array using the .load method.

Comment: Maybe I am confused. Is it the request or the response you are having trouble with? It looks like processData should be true in this case, which will convert { sndJson : jsonData } to a url-encoded POST body.

Comment: What I'm ultimately trying to do is pass an array to my php file. If I send just the array without processing I only get the last variable in the array. When I send the array as a json formatted string then I get the array returned as a string with all the quotes slashed out e.g. : Array ( [sndJson] => [\"8\",\"3\",\"6\",\"7\"] ). php will not decode this into an array.

Comment: You need to send it as a json formatted string and then decode it in PHP. It's not automatic.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

The following examples above are not reusable. I am a huge fan of reuseable code. here is my solution.

Software design 101:
DRY Don't repeat your self. You should wrap your code into an object. This way you can call it from anywhere.

```
var Request = {
    version: 1.0, //not needed but i like versioning things
    xproxy: function(type, url, data, callback, timeout, headers, contentType) 
    {
        if (!timeout || timeout <= 0) { timeout = 15000; }
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: url,
            type: type,
            data: data,
            timeout: timeout,
            contentType: contentType,
            success:function(data) 
            {
                if (callback != undefined) { callback(data); }
            },
            error:function(data) 
            {
                if (callback != undefined) { callback(data); }
            }, 
            beforeSend: function(xhr)
            {
                //headers is a list with two items
                if(headers)
                {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('secret-key', headers[0]);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('api-key', headers[1]);
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var contentType = "applicaiton/json";
var url = "http://api.lastfm.com/get/data/";
var timeout = 1000*5; //five seconds
var requestType = "POST"; //GET, POST, DELETE, PUT

var header = [];
header.push("unique-guid");
header.push("23903820983");

var data = "{\"username\":\"james\"}"; //you should really deserialize this w/ a function
function callback(data)
{
   //do logic here
}
Request.xproxy(requestType, url, data, callback, timeout, header, contentType);
</script>
```